# NUFFT of non-uniform sampling spectrometer

Tags: fft, frequency-spectrum, nonuniform

I am looking to apply Matlab's nufft.m function to a signal non-uniformly sampled with a spectrometer, hence measuring values at discrete frequencies.

In this case I believe my sample points t will be the discrete frequencies of my spectrometer and X will be my interference fringe data, following Matlab convention. What value would be required to calculate an accurate Y = nufft(X,t/ScalingFactor).

Comment: I'm not quite sure, but it sounds like you have a nonuniform frequency sampled spectrum, and you want to take the inverse Fourier transform to get a uniformly spaced time sequence? If so, you might have a look here: https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/829233-how-do-i-invert-a-non-uniform-fft-using-the-nufft-function